# PHP missing function arguments in exception stack trace

Tags: php, exception, xdebug

I am working to evolve my own error handler for my php apps and I need to send a pretty Exception report to the user on development server.
So, when it catches an Exception, it have to parse the exception stack trace to show function, line arguments, etc.
But, **I no more have the arguments** in function calls.

I think this is caused by XDebug and I tried to change the value of xdebug.collect_params to fix it but without any success.
In fact, this config only changes the display of xdebug default report that now have the function call parameters.

I made a test script to test it so I let you see.

```
<?php
$config = 'xdebug.collect_params';
echo "Current value of $config is<br />\n";
var_dump(ini_get($config));

ini_set($config, 3);

function fallDeepToHell($param) {
    echo 'Param is : ' . $param . "<br>\n";
    throw new Exception();
}

try {
    fallDeepToHell('from heaven');
} catch(Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getTrace());
    var_dump($e->getTraceAsString());
}
fallDeepToHell('from heaven');
```

The result on my development server is

[image]

I am using PHP 7.4 with FPM.

My php.ini changes:

```
max_execution_time = 30
memory_limit = 128M
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
html_errors = On
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 49M
date.timezone = Europe/Paris

;[mail function]
mail.add_x_header = On

;[Session]
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 43200
```

My XDebug settings are only about remote things.

Comment: You call `fallDeepToHell('from heaven');` at the end again without a try / catch block around. This throws an Exception wich is not caught. Best is to read the backtraced from bottom to top. You see it is engaged by line 22 which is called from the main().

Comment: I can't reproduce this, and I always see the arguments - with or without Xdebug loaded. Which version of Xdebug are you running? If you're not on 2.9.1, you should upgrade.

Comment: @Derick I am using Xdebug v2.9.1 & PHP FPM 7.4

Comment: I tried again with these versions, but it works. Would you mind sharing your phpinfo() output? Or, if possible, provide a docker setup that displays this wrong behaviour?

Comment: Here is the html of my phpinfo https://pastebin.com/HtRtaqnJ

Comment: No more help ? No solution ?

Comment: Here is my php.ini changes:
max_execution_time = 30
memory_limit = 128M
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
html_errors = On
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 49M
date.timezone = Europe/Paris

;[mail function]
mail.add_x_header = On

;[Session]
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 43200

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the same problem, it turned out to be the new `zend.exception_ignore_args` INI directive [introduced in PHP 7.4](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.other-changes.php#migration74.other-changes.ini).

> `zend.exception_ignore_args` is a new INI directive for including or
>   excluding arguments from stack traces generated from exceptions.

Comment: I set this directive to Off and it works fine now ! Thank you !

Comment: It claims to be defaulted to `off`/`0` in the PHP but setting the value to `0` again in `php.ini` did fix the issue for me. This was occurring with sentry-php for me, and this resolved arguments/vars not getting sent to Sentry.

Comment: The line of code for the lazy: `ini_set('zend.exception_ignore_args', 0);`